# App crashes when setting ImageView source to AnimationDrawable

Tags: android

Im trying to set the source of an ImageView to an AnimationDrawable but no matter what way I do it the app always crashes at that point. heres the animation resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:oneshot="false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/f11" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/f2" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/f3" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/f4" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/f5" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/f6" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/f7" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/f8" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/f9" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/f10" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/f11" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/f12" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/f13" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/f14" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

in my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/banim"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:src="@anim/anim"
        />
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:gravity="center">
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:src="@drawable/play"
        />
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/achievements"
        android:src="@drawable/achievements"
        />

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

heres my activity:

```
public class Menu extends Activity {

AnimationDrawable animationDrawable;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    ImageView gif = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.banim);
    animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable)gif.getBackground();
    animationDrawable.start();

    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    final Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Achievements.class);

    final ImageView bplay = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.play);
    final ImageView bachieve = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.achievements);

    final View.OnClickListener buttonClickListener;
    buttonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (view == bplay){
                startActivity(intent);
            }else if (view == bachieve){
                startActivity(intent1);
            }

        }
    };

    bplay.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
    bachieve.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
}

}
```

Ive tried setting it programmatically with

```
gif.setImageResource(R.anim.anim);
```

it crashes at that point. I tried moving anim to the drawable folder but still no luck.
can someone help me?

Comment: post your stacktrace please!!

Answer (score 0):

You must run your animation drawable from another thread other than the main thread, then update your code like this code snippet and it will work.

In Your activity do the follolwing:

```
public class Menu extends Activity {

    AnimationDrawable animationDrawable;
    ImageView gif ;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.menu);

            // the fix is here
            gif = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.banim);
            gif.setImageResource(R.anim.anim);

            Starter starter = new Starter();
            gif.post(starter);

            final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
            final Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Achievements.class);

            final ImageView bplay = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.play);
            final ImageView bachieve = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.achievements);

            final View.OnClickListener buttonClickListener;
            buttonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    if (view == bplay){
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else if (view == bachieve){
                        startActivity(intent1);
                    }

                }
            };

            bplay.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
            bachieve.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
        }

            class Starter implements Runnable {
                public void run() {

                    // Get the background, which has been compiled to an
                    // AnimationDrawable
                    // object.
                    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) gif
                            .getBackground();

                    frameAnimation.setOneShot(false);

                    // Start the animation (looped playback by default).
                    frameAnimation.start();
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Why would you have to run the animation on a different thread?

Comment: Because if the animation was running from your main thread, you would slow everything down considerably every time the next image waits to load